# If a function $f: [0,1] \to \mathbb R$ is continuous, does it mean that it's uniformly continuous?

Tags: calculus, general-topology, uniform-continuity

> If a function $f: [0,1] \to \mathbb R$ is continuous, does it mean that it's uniformly continuous?

I am not sure how to justify this in a quite formal way. My idea is that it does not necessarily have to be the case - even though the interval is bounded, we can still imagine a function with a very rapidly increasing slope. But, on the other hand, the interval is bounded, therefore we can't have infinitely large slopes and so the slope of every function is bounded (Lipschitz condition) therefore I'd be rather more inclined to say that this is, in fact, the case.  What do you think?

Comment: This is a special case of the [Heine-Cantor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Cantor_theorem) theorem.

Comment: The slope isn't bounded (take $x\mapsto\sqrt x$, for instance), but you are right that a function from $[0,1]$ to $\Bbb R$ that is continuous is absolutely continuous. The specific property of $[0,1]$ that allows this is called _compactness_.

Comment: @Arthur: I think you meant "uniformly" continuous instead of "absolutely" continuous in your comment.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I meant "uniformly" instead of "absolutely" continuous, you're right.

Comment: @Arthur Usually absolutely continuous means $f$ is the antiderivative of some $g \in L^1$, which is the case whenever $f$ is increasing and continuous on $[a,b]$. Of course $f$ can be piecewise increasing or decreasing, it works too. If it is not, it is more complicated.

Comment: @reuns Usually absolutely continuous means that given an $\varepsilon>0$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that for any finite collection of pairwise disjoint, open intervals of total width $\delta$, the difference between the value of $f$ at the end points of each of those intervals sum to less than $\varepsilon$. And I already said I made a mistake. I meant uniformly.

Answer (score 2):

It is a theorem that continuous functions over compact sets are uniformly continuous.

Note also that uniformly continuous is not equivalent to have a bounded derivative (although this implies uniform continuity). Even more, a function can be continuous at every point of it's domain and not be differentiable at any of them.